# Is it possible to do prediction with Poisson regression that fitting with spline functions?

Tags: r, glm, predict, spline, poisson

I am trying to do prediction with poisson regression that fitting with spline functions.
The code is as below:

```
#poisson regression
#sample dataset
set.seed(123)
index = rpois(24,26)
index = splines::bs(index)

tes = data.frame(year = c(2000:2023), count = rpois(24,277),population = ceiling(runif(24, min=200000, max=500000)),sex = ceiling(runif(24, min=-1, max=1)),index = index)

b = glm(count ~ offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + index,data = tes, family = poisson)

predict.glm(b,newdata = data.frame(sex = as.factor(0), index1 = 1,index2 = 3, index3 = 5.5,population = 260000))
```

The result of `b` is:

```
> glm(count ~ offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + index,data = tes, family = poisson)

Call:  glm(formula = count ~ offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + 
    index, family = poisson, data = tes)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  as.factor(sex)1           index1           index2           index3  
       -6.94974         -0.19003          0.09533         -0.17639         -0.17530  

Degrees of Freedom: 23 Total (i.e. Null);  19 Residual
Null Deviance:      458.5 
Residual Deviance: 403.6    AIC: 592.7
```

Then, I input new data into `predict.glm` function:

```
> predict.glm(b,newdata = data.frame(sex = as.factor(0), index1 = 1,index2 = 3, index3 = 5.5,population = 260000))
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'index')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 24 rows
```

Why I cannot get the outcome with newdata that contains only one row? Please help me to solve the problem. Thank you!

---

The data structure of `tes` and `b` is provided:

```
> dput(tes)
structure(list(year = 2000:2023, count = c(289L, 276L, 288L, 
281L, 284L, 274L, 276L, 265L, 284L, 281L, 276L, 252L, 268L, 280L, 
268L, 310L, 258L, 263L, 286L, 290L, 261L, 282L, 258L, 295L), 
    population = c(313225, 385123, 355503, 211079, 422910, 452729, 
    214735, 467987, 313454, 408670, 415194, 404758, 290122, 290787, 
    342834, 214545, 347486, 376588, 270392, 489392, 247999, 372572, 
    326238, 236729), sex = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), index.1 = c(0, 0.263374485596708, 
    0.435699588477366, 0.167181069958848, 0.263374485596708, 
    0.148662551440329, 0.263374485596708, 0.329218106995885, 
    0.411522633744856, 0.0694444444444444, 0.444444444444444, 
    0.435699588477366, 0, 0.263374485596708, 0.347222222222222, 
    0.435699588477366, 0.435699588477366, 0.411522633744856, 
    0.347222222222222, 0.329218106995885, 0.329218106995885, 
    0, 0.0329218106995885, 0.347222222222222), index.2 = c(0, 
    0.0329218106995885, 0.277263374485597, 0.434670781893004, 
    0.0329218106995885, 0.00874485596707819, 0.0329218106995885, 
    0.411522633744856, 0.329218106995885, 0.347222222222222, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.277263374485597, 0, 0.0329218106995885, 
    0.0694444444444444, 0.277263374485597, 0.277263374485597, 
    0.329218106995885, 0.0694444444444444, 0.411522633744856, 
    0.411522633744856, 0, 0.263374485596708, 0.0694444444444444
    ), index.3 = c(0, 0.00137174211248285, 0.0588134430727023, 
    0.376714677640604, 0.00137174211248285, 0.000171467764060357, 
    0.00137174211248285, 0.171467764060357, 0.0877914951989026, 
    0.578703703703704, 0.037037037037037, 0.0588134430727023, 
    0, 0.00137174211248285, 0.00462962962962963, 0.0588134430727023, 
    0.0588134430727023, 0.0877914951989026, 0.00462962962962963, 
    0.171467764060357, 0.171467764060357, 1, 0.702331961591221, 
    0.00462962962962963)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

```
> dput(b)
structure(list(coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = -6.94974487455303, 
`as.factor(sex)1` = -0.190032121125458, index1 = 0.0953262415591894, 
index2 = -0.176393713972916, index3 = -0.175296245765719), residuals = c(`1` = -0.0377735860269141, 
`2` = -0.113256060183402, `3` = 0.039907946997051, `4` = 0.575991996639709, 
`5` = -0.169080428264172, `6` = -0.246286333990354, `7` = 0.315118681163202, 
`8` = -0.233119612904975, `9` = 0.182435097615545, `10` = -0.161793839098565, 
`11` = -0.304435533755034, `12` = -0.200808642395873, `13` = 0.164983790324824, 
`14` = -0.0147606572742338, `15` = -0.0336951714689638, `16` = 0.854765356354934, 
`17` = -0.0469228148822554, `18` = -0.0885726434763727, `19` = 0.307481150379546, 
`20` = -0.197478496248273, `21` = 0.178626556325525, `22` = -0.059400080878874, 
`23` = 0.17796641261993, `24` = 0.540401007176284), fitted.values = c(`1` = 300.345111922986, 
`2` = 311.251069905348, `3` = 276.947590247444, `4` = 178.300397844114, 
`5` = 341.789999490217, `6` = 363.533278427372, `7` = 209.866990677893, 
`8` = 345.555844769784, `9` = 240.182315775897, `10` = 335.239721571365, 
`11` = 396.800028457459, `12` = 315.318725111672, `13` = 230.046119290016, 
`14` = 284.194903570691, `15` = 277.345193863317, `16` = 167.137044552754, 
`17` = 270.702104749393, `18` = 288.558378369436, `19` = 218.741203203563, 
`20` = 361.361033497884, `21` = 221.44418738849, `22` = 299.808658567071, 
`23` = 219.021524922921, `24` = 191.508573823102), effects = c(`(Intercept)` = 579.613994206578, 
`as.factor(sex)1` = 5.77923588337125, index1 = -1.72095599454427, 
index2 = 3.59288975402549, index3 = 2.5913767003459, -3.50177327657913, 
5.56520842753104, -6.12576975129712, 2.30286381961486, -4.91148220323769, 
-5.70640772881819, -3.56586998795899, 2.85986066825712, 0.915026903093524, 
0.889888390792067, 11.0504829052022, -0.772085300279466, -2.07946278339385, 
5.83626131981542, -5.58677542654504, 1.01740991531011, 1.00655831576379, 
2.01197279757831, 8.6841904066532), R = structure(c(-81.5168769464662, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -54.2096432841718, -38.4748670681331, 0, 0, 0, -22.1255268392986, 
-4.46305667530611, -11.4880400055247, 0, 0, -15.5818529062711, 
-0.936196658979598, -5.40064899749766, -11.5912956244503, 0, 
-12.2736534462079, 7.25581712839338, 9.00467004055709, -8.83223746354445, 
-14.7828419771706), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", 
"as.factor(sex)1", "index1", "index2", "index3"), c("(Intercept)", 
"as.factor(sex)1", "index1", "index2", "index3"))), rank = 5L, 
    qr = structure(list(qr = structure(c(-81.5168769464662, 0.216425242377649, 
    0.204150914167575, 0.163805576180608, 0.226794313854213, 
    0.233896947032175, 0.177715199617014, 0.228040324633816, 
    0.190117917480786, 0.224610594546886, 0.244364659471823, 
    0.217834876925864, 0.186062948652436, 0.206804816314754, 
    0.20429739272982, 0.158594781471836, 0.20183586949614, 0.208386403283321, 
    0.18143363441611, 0.23319712339217, 0.182551199810134, 0.212409796655831, 
    0.181549838588646, 0.169764396143524, -54.2096432841718, 
    -38.4748670681331, 0.195325321657711, -0.190331481970975, 
    0.216989830706082, 0.223785411885617, -0.206493564508326, 
    0.21818197553339, 0.181898981624677, -0.260982979476565, 
    -0.283935924912126, 0.208417716752846, 0.178019312048183, 
    -0.240293817131863, 0.195465467845168, 0.151738613713937, 
    0.193110358051284, 0.199377707498275, 0.173590126433453, 
    0.223115842130591, -0.212112683863296, -0.246806441668888, 
    0.173701307015088, 0.162425357819082, -22.1255268392986, 
    -4.46305667530611, -11.4880400055247, 0.00498173623105425, 
    -0.0171239249324329, -0.208046089482519, 0.126707754590126, 
    0.0893254944572615, 0.185502989917272, -0.148940950868519, 
    0.488196354104526, 0.249917793143135, -0.361772956809709, 
    0.147448130323893, 0.106124910680894, 0.181952763252637, 
    0.231562437537348, 0.203328025992443, 0.0942480370876956, 
    0.0913454600034699, 0.215446105287386, -0.245518443544009, 
    -0.310586595893575, 0.088186301042782, -15.5818529062711, 
    -0.936196658979598, -5.40064899749766, -11.5912956244503, 
    -0.170216683642676, -0.114228957062525, -0.241799120034846, 
    0.379445681128552, 0.147348516985548, 0.354973727333446, 
    -0.17387096182488, 0.0693961416954329, 0.00190282799975146, 
    -0.281378422957854, -0.165396703599046, 0.0505238926038525, 
    0.0642993022808831, 0.161507278696406, -0.146886480798631, 
    0.388026290809968, 0.192386230733565, -0.127411657095816, 
    0.315605679577016, -0.137439206322886, -12.2736534462079, 
    7.25581712839338, 9.00467004055709, -8.83223746354445, -14.7828419771706, 
    -0.0755029539268413, -0.0345004736917962, 0.00419675355530128, 
    0.0625278096053374, 0.156491138324304, 0.0592530807175311, 
    0.110052408952578, -0.20434262229919, -0.0401477427928503, 
    0.110979058678401, 0.080123706518416, 0.101969546679378, 
    0.0685361249560151, 0.0985589374932929, 0.00429165700519685, 
    -0.0709287448173044, 0.85157215243401, 0.347992198140049, 
    0.0922199379511), dim = c(24L, 5L), dimnames = list(c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23", "24"), c("(Intercept)", "as.factor(sex)1", "index1", 
    "index2", "index3"))), rank = 5L, qraux = c(1.21259974911287, 
    1.20706902173146, 1.23421844406614, 1.29929823379014, 1.04826448606473
    ), pivot = 1:5, tol = 1e-11), class = "qr"), family = structure(list(
        family = "poisson", link = "log", linkfun = function (mu) 
        log(mu), linkinv = function (eta) 
        pmax(exp(eta), .Machine$double.eps), variance = function (mu) 
        mu, dev.resids = function (y, mu, wt) 
        {
            r <- mu * wt
            p <- which(y > 0)
            r[p] <- (wt * (y * log(y/mu) - (y - mu)))[p]
            2 * r
        }, aic = function (y, n, mu, wt, dev) 
        -2 * sum(dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) * wt), mu.eta = function (eta) 
        pmax(exp(eta), .Machine$double.eps), initialize = expression(
            {
                if (any(y < 0)) 
                  stop("negative values not allowed for the 'Poisson' family")
                n <- rep.int(1, nobs)
                mustart <- y + 0.1
            }), validmu = function (mu) 
        all(is.finite(mu)) && all(mu > 0), valideta = function (eta) 
        TRUE, simulate = function (object, nsim) 
        {
            wts <- object$prior.weights
            if (any(wts != 1)) 
                warning("ignoring prior weights")
            ftd <- fitted(object)
            rpois(nsim * length(ftd), ftd)
        }), class = "family"), linear.predictors = c(`1` = 5.70493218656073, 
    `2` = 5.74059988521991, `3` = 5.62382828340296, `4` = 5.18346975618525, 
    `5` = 5.83419651188663, `6` = 5.89587084278965, `7` = 5.34647395232474, 
    `8` = 5.84515426479107, `9` = 5.48139828402091, `10` = 5.81484586269512, 
    `11` = 5.9834324471281, `12` = 5.75358395302634, `13` = 5.43827980747426, 
    `14` = 5.64966028295714, `15` = 5.62526291757272, `16` = 5.11881410195168, 
    `17` = 5.6010189718002, `18` = 5.66489741684507, `19` = 5.38788931050255, 
    `20` = 5.88987755136518, `21` = 5.40017058206125, `22` = 5.70314446639578, 
    `23` = 5.38917001230589, `24` = 5.25493257954067), deviance = 403.600408677454, 
    aic = 592.662157401933, null.deviance = 458.519802336079, 
    iter = 4L, weights = c(`1` = 300.345106793882, `2` = 311.251096878971, 
    `3` = 276.947674937809, `4` = 178.300445731354, `5` = 341.790029110402, 
    `6` = 363.533277399018, `7` = 209.867028257601, `8` = 345.555943097104, 
    `9` = 240.182390179855, `10` = 335.239774876442, `11` = 396.800180053365, 
    `12` = 315.318821535902, `13` = 230.04609410461, `14` = 284.194954459883, 
    `15` = 277.345238189581, `16` = 167.137095663137, `17` = 270.702187529893, 
    `18` = 288.558467759387, `19` = 218.741238163535, `20` = 361.361136322544, 
    `21` = 221.444270862045, `22` = 299.808645163085, `23` = 219.021525605252, 
    `24` = 191.508604430661), prior.weights = c(`1` = 1, `2` = 1, 
    `3` = 1, `4` = 1, `5` = 1, `6` = 1, `7` = 1, `8` = 1, `9` = 1, 
    `10` = 1, `11` = 1, `12` = 1, `13` = 1, `14` = 1, `15` = 1, 
    `16` = 1, `17` = 1, `18` = 1, `19` = 1, `20` = 1, `21` = 1, 
    `22` = 1, `23` = 1, `24` = 1), df.residual = 19L, df.null = 23L, 
    y = c(`1` = 289L, `2` = 276L, `3` = 288L, `4` = 281L, `5` = 284L, 
    `6` = 274L, `7` = 276L, `8` = 265L, `9` = 284L, `10` = 281L, 
    `11` = 276L, `12` = 252L, `13` = 268L, `14` = 280L, `15` = 268L, 
    `16` = 310L, `17` = 258L, `18` = 263L, `19` = 286L, `20` = 290L, 
    `21` = 261L, `22` = 282L, `23` = 258L, `24` = 295L), converged = TRUE, 
    boundary = FALSE, model = structure(list(count = c(289L, 
    276L, 288L, 281L, 284L, 274L, 276L, 265L, 284L, 281L, 276L, 
    252L, 268L, 280L, 268L, 310L, 258L, 263L, 286L, 290L, 261L, 
    282L, 258L, 295L), `offset(log(population))` = c(12.6546770611138, 
    12.8613180427664, 12.7812889670084, 12.2599877499681, 12.9549146694331, 
    13.0230489914562, 12.2771599887457, 13.0561957967362, 12.6554078978266, 
    12.9206632633838, 12.9365011598623, 12.9110446366318, 12.5780568031527, 
    12.5803463193781, 12.7450016439846, 12.2762747855571, 12.7584796554056, 
    12.8389070306508, 12.5076280369145, 13.1009190833103, 12.4211799928809, 
    12.8281855867145, 12.6953824553334, 12.3746713059526), `as.factor(sex)` = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
        index = structure(c(0, 0.263374485596708, 0.435699588477366, 
        0.167181069958848, 0.263374485596708, 0.148662551440329, 
        0.263374485596708, 0.329218106995885, 0.411522633744856, 
        0.0694444444444444, 0.444444444444444, 0.435699588477366, 
        0, 0.263374485596708, 0.347222222222222, 0.435699588477366, 
        0.435699588477366, 0.411522633744856, 0.347222222222222, 
        0.329218106995885, 0.329218106995885, 0, 0.0329218106995885, 
        0.347222222222222, 0, 0.0329218106995885, 0.277263374485597, 
        0.434670781893004, 0.0329218106995885, 0.00874485596707819, 
        0.0329218106995885, 0.411522633744856, 0.329218106995885, 
        0.347222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 0.277263374485597, 
        0, 0.0329218106995885, 0.0694444444444444, 0.277263374485597, 
        0.277263374485597, 0.329218106995885, 0.0694444444444444, 
        0.411522633744856, 0.411522633744856, 0, 0.263374485596708, 
        0.0694444444444444, 0, 0.00137174211248285, 0.0588134430727023, 
        0.376714677640604, 0.00137174211248285, 0.000171467764060357, 
        0.00137174211248285, 0.171467764060357, 0.0877914951989026, 
        0.578703703703704, 0.037037037037037, 0.0588134430727023, 
        0, 0.00137174211248285, 0.00462962962962963, 0.0588134430727023, 
        0.0588134430727023, 0.0877914951989026, 0.00462962962962963, 
        0.171467764060357, 0.171467764060357, 1, 0.702331961591221, 
        0.00462962962962963), dim = c(24L, 3L), dimnames = list(
            NULL, c("1", "2", "3")), degree = 3L, knots = numeric(0), Boundary.knots = c(20L, 
        38L), intercept = FALSE, class = c("bs", "basis", "matrix"
        ))), terms = count ~ offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + 
        index, row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame"), 
    call = glm(formula = count ~ offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + 
        index, family = poisson, data = tes), formula = count ~ 
        offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + index, terms = count ~ 
        offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + index, data = structure(list(
        year = 2000:2023, count = c(289L, 276L, 288L, 281L, 284L, 
        274L, 276L, 265L, 284L, 281L, 276L, 252L, 268L, 280L, 
        268L, 310L, 258L, 263L, 286L, 290L, 261L, 282L, 258L, 
        295L), population = c(313225, 385123, 355503, 211079, 
        422910, 452729, 214735, 467987, 313454, 408670, 415194, 
        404758, 290122, 290787, 342834, 214545, 347486, 376588, 
        270392, 489392, 247999, 372572, 326238, 236729), sex = c(0, 
        1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 0, 0, 1, 1), index.1 = c(0, 0.263374485596708, 0.435699588477366, 
        0.167181069958848, 0.263374485596708, 0.148662551440329, 
        0.263374485596708, 0.329218106995885, 0.411522633744856, 
        0.0694444444444444, 0.444444444444444, 0.435699588477366, 
        0, 0.263374485596708, 0.347222222222222, 0.435699588477366, 
        0.435699588477366, 0.411522633744856, 0.347222222222222, 
        0.329218106995885, 0.329218106995885, 0, 0.0329218106995885, 
        0.347222222222222), index.2 = c(0, 0.0329218106995885, 
        0.277263374485597, 0.434670781893004, 0.0329218106995885, 
        0.00874485596707819, 0.0329218106995885, 0.411522633744856, 
        0.329218106995885, 0.347222222222222, 0.222222222222222, 
        0.277263374485597, 0, 0.0329218106995885, 0.0694444444444444, 
        0.277263374485597, 0.277263374485597, 0.329218106995885, 
        0.0694444444444444, 0.411522633744856, 0.411522633744856, 
        0, 0.263374485596708, 0.0694444444444444), index.3 = c(0, 
        0.00137174211248285, 0.0588134430727023, 0.376714677640604, 
        0.00137174211248285, 0.000171467764060357, 0.00137174211248285, 
        0.171467764060357, 0.0877914951989026, 0.578703703703704, 
        0.037037037037037, 0.0588134430727023, 0, 0.00137174211248285, 
        0.00462962962962963, 0.0588134430727023, 0.0588134430727023, 
        0.0877914951989026, 0.00462962962962963, 0.171467764060357, 
        0.171467764060357, 1, 0.702331961591221, 0.00462962962962963
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L)), offset = c(12.6546770611138, 
    12.8613180427664, 12.7812889670084, 12.2599877499681, 12.9549146694331, 
    13.0230489914562, 12.2771599887457, 13.0561957967362, 12.6554078978266, 
    12.9206632633838, 12.9365011598623, 12.9110446366318, 12.5780568031527, 
    12.5803463193781, 12.7450016439846, 12.2762747855571, 12.7584796554056, 
    12.8389070306508, 12.5076280369145, 13.1009190833103, 12.4211799928809, 
    12.8281855867145, 12.6953824553334, 12.3746713059526), control = list(
        epsilon = 1e-08, maxit = 25, trace = FALSE), method = "glm.fit", 
    contrasts = list(`as.factor(sex)` = "contr.treatment"), xlevels = list(
        `as.factor(sex)` = c("0", "1"))), class = c("glm", "lm"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

`tes` does not contain a column `index`, so `glm` isn't taking `index` from the data.frame but from the global environment. You could do `index = cbind(1, 1, 1)` before calling `predict` and it would work but the proper way would be this:

```
set.seed(123)
tes = data.frame(year = c(2000:2023), count = rpois(24,277),
                 population = ceiling(runif(24, min=200000, max=500000)),
                 sex = ceiling(runif(24, min=-1, max=1)),
                 index = rpois(24,26))
b = glm(count ~ offset(log(population)) + as.factor(sex) + splines::bs(index),
        data = tes, family = poisson)
summary(b)
predict.glm(b,
            newdata = data.frame(sex = factor(0, levels = c(0, 1)),
                                 population = 260000, index = 20))
```

Comment: I am using epi::apc.fit to do prediction. In this function, the `index` after passing to splines::bs did not return. So, I am not able to get the data of `index` after transformation of `bs`. I am wondering whether it is possible to do prediction without the original bs(index) or not.

Comment: Sorry, we can't help you if your reproducible example doesn't reflect your actual issue.